# Can you use App Store Sandbox testing (verifyReceipt specifically) before submitting the app or the related IAPs?

Tags: swift, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I've been trying to use the `verifyReceipt` endpoint to verify in-app purchase transactions with no success.

Here's how I'm doing it.

**1.** Read the receipt data in iOS (this is copy paste [from Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)):

```
if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

    do {
        let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
        print(receiptData)

        let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

        // sendReceiptToBackEnd(receiptString)
    }
    catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
}
```

**2.** In the backend, I followed [this advice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) from Apple:

> As a best practice, always call the production URL for verifyReceipt first, and proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code.

So first I try this (python code):

```
data = {
    'receipt-data': receipt_string, # this is what we get from the frontend
    'password': settings.APP_STORE_SHARED_SECRET
}
url = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
response_data = response.json()
status = response_data['status']
```

Status here is `21007`, which is expected according to the advice above. So then I try the sandbox:

```
url = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt'
response = requests.post(url, json=data)
response_data = response.json()
status = response_data['status']
```

And I get `21002` - which means there's probably something wrong with what I sent.

Initially I was trying to test this [using Xcode locally](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_in_xcode), but I found out later that `verifyReceipt` doesn't work with this feature because app's are not signed by the App Store. So I deleted the local configs and set the StoreKit Configuration in scheme back to `none`, and verified the app is using the App Store Connect as it was picking up any changes I made there in the price.

I'm out of ideas on how to debug this further, so I'm wondering could it be because the App & IAPs are not submitted yet? Currently the app is in the "Prepare for Submission" state, and the IAPs are in the "Ready to Submit" state. Or maybe there is something else I'm missing?

**Edit:** The answer to my question is "yes, you can." I copied and pasted the json and sent it manually using Postman and it worked fine so something is happening in the backend. I'm leaving the question for reference but if someone recommends deleting please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your edit, but just as a follow-up code 21002 is a "malformed body" response (or theoretically an Apple server issue, but I've only seen it when mangling the receipt data).

You can see the full list of codes and meanings here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status

Incidentally, as you build our your server to process iTunes responses you may find this guide useful for processing the receipt on the server:

https://www.namiml.com/blog/app-store-verify-receipt-definitive-guide

Comment: Thank you - my issue was a stupid and hard to spot bug I introduced while working late on this :)